# Mac open file dialog - "search" function - does not show all matching files

Tags: finder, search

When considering the contents of the **/shared** directory - and specifically the files whose names begin with *driversLicense*:

16:12:48/shared $ll driversLicense.*

> ```
> -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 steve  staff  567710 Aug  1  2011 driversLicense.pdf
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff    6476 Aug 27  2013 driversLicense.2013.jpg
> -rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  314030 Nov 10  2014 driversLicense.jpg
> ```

Then in Finder I type in first few letters - specifically driversLicense: here is the screenshot of the result (I have done this a half dozen times to ensure it were repeatable):

[image]

Why is it that "driversLicense.2013.jpg" appears but not "driversLicense.jpg and driversLicense.pdf" ??

Comment: Your Finder window is sorted by date modified - try by name.

Comment: If I type in driversLicense why would that matter? i.e. Why would it show only one of the matches and not all three?

Comment: because you're typing straight into the Finder window. It will give you the first hit - it's not a filter, it's a 'go to'. It's expected behaviour. Try the same thing using sort by name. It will hit the first one alphabetically, the others will be below it, but not selected.

Comment: ah! I did not 'get' that goto intention. thx

Comment: @Tetsujin  Pls make your comment an answer and I will award.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing directly into a Finder window doesn't generate a 'search' as such;  there is no filter generated, it merely selects the first match to your typed string.

So, if your folder is sorted by anything other than Name, then it will find the first match, yet not necessarily the first alphabetically - in your case it should find the newest match.

Setting the sort to Name, the same string will find & select the first match alphabetically - the others will be directly beneath it, unselected.